# How to display remote swf in flex UI component?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I am trying to display remote swf in my flex application, I am able to load swf, but it is not shown(visble) in my flex application.

here is the code

```
private function onLoaderComplete(event:Event):void{
            can.addChild(l);
        }


            import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
            import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
                             var l:Loader = new Loader();

            private function initApp():void {  
            var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();

            l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
            if(Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE){
                var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
                context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
                l.load(new URLRequest('www.somedomain.com/load.swf?id1'), context);
            }else{
                l.load(new URLRequest('www.somedomain.com/load.swf?id=1'));
            }

private function onLoaderComplete(event:Event):void{
            can.addChild(l);
        }


<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="50%" backgroundColor="red">
    <mx:UIComponent id="can" width="100%" height="100%" >

    </mx:UIComponent>
</mx:Canvas>
```

any idea

Thanks all

Comment: did you check your remote swf? what do contentloaderinfo dimensions say?

Comment: Width and height are zero. However after getting data,i mean once swf loaded, width and height are set manually, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet does not define what 'L' is

The most likely problem you're having with your current code is that you are adding your 'l' onto a UIComponent which has no built in code for sizing and positioning its children, therefore your 'l' will have no height and width, effectively making it invisible.

I would use a [SWFLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#methodSummary) to load another SWF File and display it as part of your application.

Comment: l is variable of type loader.I have tried SWFLoader, but no luck. I have edited code in question now

Comment: With your edited code; you still aren't sizing the loader; as such I Guess it has no height or width.

Comment: Are you sure the SWF you're loading has something to display?  Can you load the SWF straight in the browser and see stuff? Are you sure the SWF is loading? Does onLoderComplete method actually fire?  What if you add listeners for the other events, such as IO Error or HTTP Status?

Comment: I can access SWF in browser. onLoaderComplete event fires. I did not saw any error event while loading. it is very strange.